# PHP - Unix timestamp to DateTime string, maintaining milliseconds precision

Tags: php, datetime, epoch

I have a timestamp

> 1457459333506 (Tue, 08 Mar 2016 17:48:53 GMT)

This should be Unix timestamp with milliseconds. I want to write this as a string, so I'm using

```
$dt = new DateTime("@$unixTimestamp");
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s.u', $unixTimestamp) . "<br>";
```

But the output is **2016-06-08 22:09:22.000000**

This is obviously wrong, and has no milisecond precision. So I've tried

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s.u', $unixTimestamp / 1000) . "<br>";
```

Which outputs as **2016-03-08 17:48:53.000000** (correct, but also has no milisecond precision).

How can I get this to output correctly as: **2016-03-08 17:48:53.506** ?

Comment: FYI, Unix / POSIX / Epoch / time is defined as number of **seconds** ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)). What you have a timestamp multiplied by 1000.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As simple as

```
$unixTimestamp = 1457459333506;
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat("U.u", $unixTimestamp / 1000);
var_dump($dt);
```

with a DateTime object

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/oOflj)

Comment: `\DateTime::createFromFormat("U", $timestampInMiliseconds / 1000);`